How to make Toggle Functionality with QT?
I want to make one toggle functionality in QT like when I click on the pushButton then I want something else in the Label and when I click another time then I want another text value.
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(bool checked)
{
    if (checked) {
        ui->label->setText("Yupp It's working..!!");
    }
    else {
        ui->label->setText("Toggle completed..!!");
    }

}

So what I want is that when I click for the first time I want Yupp It's working..!! and second time Toggle completed..!! and third time repeat this.
I try 2 slots

clicked()
toggled()

But it is not working for both slots. It looks like not go inside the function.

Keep a bool variable somewhere and toggle it when clicking.

Note that the Auto-Connect feature is not recommended by Qt. Using the Qt5 signal and slot syntax (i.e. explicitly calling connect with function pointers) has the advantage that connection issues are detected at compile time.

Granted the button is checkable, your approach should work; which means some code absent from your question is incorrect. Please provide a proper MRE (expected 30-40 lines of code, most of it being a mock-up MainWindow class and the main function).

Check the return value of the signal-slot connect, if the return value is not valid, means your connect is invalid,  qt creator can give the error info of the connect.

To achieve toggle functionality in Qt using a QPushButton, you need to make sure your button is set to be checkable (setCheckable(true)), as you mentioned. Here’s how you can modify your code to toggle between two different texts each time the button is clicked:
Ensure your QPushButton is set to be checkable in the constructor of your MainWindow class:
ui->pushButton->setCheckable(true);

